# How to get all request parameter names and values in a form submitted using ajax in spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

I am submitting a form in spring g MVC using ajax. The form is being generated dynamically. Hence I do not know  the names of the request parameters submitted in the form.

In a simple form submission (not Ajax), I used to get all the parameter names and their values using the following code.

```
Enumeration requestParameters = request.getParameterNames();
while (requestParameters.hasMoreElements()) {
    String element = (String) requestParameters.nextElement();
    String value = request.getParameter(element);
}
```

But the same code does not work when I submit the form using ajax. Below is the code I am using to submit the form using ajax.

```
$.post("saveEntity", function() {
     alert("SUCCESS");
});
```

And below is my controller class method which gets called on the form submission.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/saveEntity")
public @ResponseBody
void saveEntity( HttpServletRequest request) {

    Enumeration requestParameters = request.getParameterNames();

    while (requestParameters.hasMoreElements()) {
        String element = (String) requestParameters.nextElement();
        String value = request.getParameter(element);

        if (element != null && value != null) {
            logger.info("param Name : " + element
                    + " value: " + value);

        }
    }

}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by making sure whats being sent to the server, either look at request in firebug  net panel or by using fiddler and make sure data is being sent properly.

XMLHttpRequest monitoring
http://getfirebug.com/network

**Edit**

You are not sending any data along with your $.post.

```
$.post({
       url: "saveEntity", 
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                }
       });
```

**Edit 2**

Make sure $('form') is actually selecting the form which you want to post.
If not, provide correct jquery selector by specifying form id. 
Once correct form is selected use `alert($('form').serialize());` to make sure its returning data in this format `{elementname1: elementvalue, elementname2: elementvalue2}`. 
If not then make sure elements have name attribute assigned to  them.

Comment: Ok so no parameters are being sent. But why?

Comment: When I am doing this  $.post("saveEntity",  { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ,function() {}); This works. But not when I use $('form').serialize().

Comment: edited again. and just for now I will suggest you use the object syntax with $.post instead of multiple parameters. since I cant be sure if you are missing something  in multiple param syntax.

Comment: Hi. I can now send the params from the JSP. But how do I get this params in the spring MVC controller. When i do request.getParameterNames(), I get only one param which is long JSON string sent from the JSP with value blank e.g. param name is {name:'John'} and the param value is ''. I want 'name' as the param and 'John' as the value. Please help.

Comment: can you show the code for `$.post()` becoz `data:$('form').serialize()` sends everything as seperate parameters

Comment: also check the firebug net panel. it must be sending them seperately. if possible post the paramteres being sent here as well

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery then you can use

```
alert($('form').serialize());
```

to get the query string

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery, But when I do as you have said , all I get is a blank.

Comment: if your form fields are unknown to you and you want to send all these value via ajax then second parameter will be like this $.post('saveEntity',$('form').serialize(),function(){}); You can get these variable in your server using $_POST[] variable.